# SSRS: expand the ultimate group of values by default upon initial execution

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

Is there a way to get SSRS to expand the ultimate group of values by default upon **initial execution**, regardless of values?

My report looks like this:

[Current scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLfs9.png)

What I want to achieve:

[Ideal Scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6B60.png)

I've searched for an answer without any success, I can't even find a similar question! Most require the current date values which can be done through the visibility settings and setting an expression to hide when not current date (or if not date then a specific value) - I get that. That's not what i'm asking, I simply want the **ultimate** values to be displayed when the report is initially rendered.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/9/19/expand-or-collapse-all-grouped-items-on-ssrs-report.html I think you are asking for something similar to this.

Comment: Almost, the link provided explains how to expand/collapse all. At the end there is mention of expanding a (nested) group at a time - however i want to expand all groups for the last record only.